# Windows Mobile Pocket PC how to mute | unmute (microphone)

Tags: windows-mobile

How can i mute | unmute a windows mobile pocket pc device (i'm using symbol MC70) programmatically? Waht API do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [waveOutSetVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908146.aspx).
**EDIT:** Check this [link](http://www.pocketpcdn.com/articles/soundvolume.html) too.

Comment: waveOutSetVolume is only in Windows Mobile 6.

Comment: @plinth: incorrect.  It's been available since at least CE 2.0, so it's been in every version of Pocket PC and WinMo ever shipped.

Comment: Very good, then.  I saw it in the reference for "new in sound APIs in Windows Mobile 6".

Comment: @ctacke: what API to use for mute | unmute microphone? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You device runs Windows Mobile 5.  From there you'll want to look at the [Hardware Audio Mixer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923403.aspx), which looks like the right API for setting/controlling audio properties on the device.